# Issue disabling years below 18 years in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

Working on a form whereby am using bootstrap datepicker to display date to the user. I have a date of birth field whereby am trying to disable years of any user that is below 18 years from the current date. For instance since we are in 2019, the datepicker should only show years below 2001 e.g 2001 , 2000, 1999 , 1998 , 1997 etc

This works fine (years) but I have a problem disabling the months and the specific days, For instance since we are in 01/02/2019 , the datepicker should disable any date after 1st February 2001

**Date of birth**

```
//dob
<div class="form-line registar love">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth *" class="form-input" name="dob" id="dob" value="#" title="You should be over 18 years old" required>

      <label class="error error-tip" for="dob" id="dobErr" style="display: none; color:red; font-size: 11px;">You should be over 18 years old</label>
 </div>
//end dob
```

**Javascript Logic**

```
var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);
$( function() {
  $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: maxBirthdayDate,
    yearRange: '1900:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear(),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate using `minDate` and `maxDate` in very simple way to prevent users selecting DOB before 18 years.

```js
$("#dob").datepicker( { minDate: '-30Y',dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', maxDate: '-18Y' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="dob" /></p>
```

Comment: ,, Your suggestion aint working, I want years, months and dates below 18 years from current year disabled,.. Kindly rwad my question again ..

Comment: @Martin `$("#dob").datepicker( { minDate: '-30Y',dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', maxDate: '-18Y' });` This can solve

Comment: Did you try this @Martin

Comment: Hey Can you handle this question : [bootstrapdatepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346835/disabling-180-days-after-the-current-date-in-bootstrap-datepicker/54358589?noredirect=1#comment95535814_54358589)  I added it a week ago,, have been researching but cant seem to figure out the solution.. Would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: I've answered that question as well. Have a look @Martin

Answer (score 2):

for bootstrap-datepicker (^1.9.0) I have solved it using.

```
$('#dob').datepicker({ endDate: '-18Y' });
```

Comment: amazing dear, don't know why but I was missing this easy thing, instead of years, I was using +0d, thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

with JS date and bootstrap datepicker :

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear() -18;
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
} 
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
} 
var yearsago = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
```

or with Moment.js

`var yearsago = moment(new Date()).subtract(18, 'years').format("DD-MM-YYYY");`

```
$('#dob').datepicker('setStartDate', yearsago);
```

or

```
$('#dob').datepicker({ 
   startDate: yearsago
});
```

Comment: ,, Confused on how to implement your logic on the datepicker

Comment: for me minDate is not working with bootstrap datepicker. it is working fine with js datepicker. for bootstrap datepicker use startDate instead  of min date and simply pass date before 18 years in it